# Using an ACCDB file (access 2007) that had to move, not connecting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access-2007

I'm writing a work request form in Visual Basic Express 2012 for Desktop. The records are managed in a ACCDB file (Access 2007). I originally built everything on my C drive to make sure I could make it work and demo for others. I made it and it works and they like it. The ACCDB file needs to go on a network accessible drive. I copy the file over and in VB in the Database Explorer, I've Modified Connections to point to the new file.
The App.Config shows the correct connection string:

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\NYHOME\users\hr\DatabaseQuote1.accdb"
```

But it is not working correctly. In Solutions Explorer, when I click on the .accdb file and look in Properties>Full Path, it still shows my C drive path.

Clearly I'm missing something!
Can someone help?

Comment: I think when you use a network named path it needs to start with a double slash.

Comment: It does. "\\NYHOME..." I only mistyped it on here.

Comment: "But it is not working correctly", what error are you getting? Are you using the my.settings connection string variable when creating the connection, instead of the file path in your code? Or did you use the .XSD to create your queries? Note, I show the app.config connection for my db is: `connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;\\server\accessdb.accdb&quot;"` so make sure yours has the &quot

Comment: I'm not getting errors. I'm setting the file path for a network drive in the Database Explorer. I double check that it shows a change in the App.Config. But in the Solutions Explorer the properties for "...accdb" still shows a C drive Full Path. Are there more settings I have to change in other places that i'm not aware of? That is my question.
Also, when I change the path for a network drive in the Database Explorer, I can click "Test Connection" it says it works. I save the project. But if I close VS and reopen it, the file path in the Database Explorer has reverted back to my C drive.

Comment: This is the entire App.Config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Quote.My.MySettings.DatabaseQuote1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\NYHOME\users\hr\DatabaseQuote1.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>